# detection of window bottom only work for once on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, safari

I am using below code to detect scroll to bottom of page, but in my webpage it only can trigger only once(in other browser it works well):

```
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                            alert('bottom');
                            get_page();
                    }
                    });
```

The page is actually located at: http://www.haorenao.com/life/

Answer (score 3):

you could see if e.scrollTop == e.scrollHeight - e.height

if "e" is the window you could take clientHeight as the e.height

Comment: the document and window are two different objects. if you want to check if the scroll is at the bottom of the page you just have to verify the above expression where "e" is any element on the page even if he is body or document, but for what you need you could check if document.body.scrollTop == document.body.scrollHeight - window.clientHeight, because the exact height for display is not the height of the body ( unless overflow is set to hidden ).

Comment: Thanks, but such code runs well on other devices including all the browser in PC. From your explanation I can't see any clue regarding the difference between ipad and PC.

Comment: there is none regarding the browser, except the fancy touch events. My only question is do you use a browser on ipad for this page or something else ( AIR or ZINC ).

Comment: thanks i changed the code to: if  ($(window).scrollTop() <= $(document).height() - $(window).height()){  and it works now!!

Comment: No problem. I do not work with jQuery but i know how to implement from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
window.onscroll = function() { 
   if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
       alert('bottom');
       get_page();
   }
};
```